# Graphene: How to add a function before query execute?

Tags: annotations, graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to execute a function before all query?

When I add an annotation above Query class, It makes an error

```
AssertionError: Type <function Query at 0x104d1dd30> is not a valid ObjectType.


def my_func(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def my_func_wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        //do something
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return my_func_wrap

@my_func
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()

    users = graphene.List(lambda: UserSchema)

    def resolve_users(self, info):
        //do something
        return User.query.all()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

If i add the annotation to every resolver, It works fine.

but I will add more than 20 resolvers and I don't think adding the annotation to every resolver is good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just create a custom View class inheriting from `GraphQLView` and override `dispatch` method then use your own view class as graphql endpoint handler. Something like this:

```
    class CustomGraphQLView(GraphQLView):
        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            // do something
            super(CustomGraphqlView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to manipulate the queryset itself, I suggest to use `graphene-django-extras` and override the `list_resolver` method on its query fields(`DjangoFilterListField`, `DjangoFilterPaginateListField`, ...) class and use your own custom class.

You can call super on override methods or copy the exact code from their source and edit them.